# How can I make my .git repository listen only to a specific folder?

Tags: git

I currently have a project done in angular.js. I use gulp to minify the files and these are saved in the "_build" folder. I just want to upload the changes that are made in the "_build" folder. Keep in mind that when I generate the minification of the files, all the content inside "_build" is deleted.

How can I make my repository listen only to the "_build" folder?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `.gitignore` file inside your `_build` directory for this:

```
# _build/.gitignore
*
!/.gitignore
```

Comment: Note that for the `.gitignore` file to be taken into account by `git`, you should create it when the `_build` directory is empty (ie `git status` says there are no changes in this directory)